# AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'join' in python 2.7.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

```
import multiprocessing
q = multiprocessing.Queue() 

def create_jobs():
    for link in file_to_set(QUEUE_FILE):
        q.put(link)
    q.join() **#here i'm getting Attribute Error**
    crawl()
```

(this is not whole snippet of code. but my function gives error only here.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Queue` is the wrong object. You want `Queue.Queue`, i.e.:

```
import Queue
q = Queue.Queue()
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex Hall